# Kernel editing of my boot loader?

Tags: boot, kernel, nomodeset

My i686 with server 12.04 386 boots to a black screen.  I read a post that said I need to edit the kernel of the boot loader.  The installation went smooth except for the black boot screen.  How do I go about this, as I am lost and awash with information overload.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to edit the kernel of the boot loader.

This doesn't make sense. What you *meant* to say was that you need to modify the kernel *commandline* - or, in other words: you need to give the Linux kernel some extra parameters at boot.

All you need to do is edit `/etc/default/grub`. Open a terminal and execute:

```
pkexec gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line that starts "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=". Add `nomodeset` to the end of whatever is in the quotes (even if there's nothing in the quotes).

When you're done, save and close gedit. Then execute:

```
sudo update-grub
```

You will be prompted to type your password. Even though there's no characters on screen, your password input is still being accepted.

Reboot.